# How to Upload NSDictionary in Memory to Dropbox, IOS

Tags: ios, memory, file-upload, nsdictionary, dropbox

I have an xml string that I want to upload as a .plist to a dropbox folder.

Currently I create a NSDictionary and create a temp folder, I write dictionary as a plist to that temp folder and upload that .plist in that temp folder to dropbox.

Which is I guess not a good programming solution;

This works ok

```
if([title isEqualToString:@"Upload to Dropbox"])
    {


        //pass string in memory to nsdictionary
        NSData * data = [_uploadPlistString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *errorDesc = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        NSDictionary *uploadFile= (NSDictionary*)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                         propertyListFromData:data
                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                         format:&format
                                         errorDescription:&errorDesc];


        //create a temp folder
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"];
        NSLog(@"documents datapath: %@",dataPath);
        //check if folder exist
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder



        //write dictionary to plist
        NSString *pathTemp = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"agenda.plist"];
        // write plist to disk
        [uploadFile writeToFile:pathTemp atomically:YES];


        //get last created file name from singleton
        SingletonClass *sharedInstance=[SingletonClass sharedInstance];
        NSString *destDirectory= sharedInstance.lastCreatedFolderName;

        //set file name for dropbox
        NSString *filename = @"agenda.plist";
        [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDirectory
                        withParentRev:nil fromPath:pathTemp];


    }
```

**But How can I upload NSDictionary that is in memory, directly to Dropbox?**

Without writing it to bundle or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Public API of the Dropbox SDK only support uploads directly from files.

However, since the SDK is open source you can easily extend it.

The main upload is happening in

```
- (void)uploadFile:(NSString*)filename toPath:(NSString*)path fromPath:(NSString *)sourcePath
params:(NSDictionary *)params
```

in DBRestClient.m.

You could add a category to DBRestClient and add a similar method for the upload that takes an NSData instead of a file path.

You can copy most of thier implementation, but instead of a filename you take an NSData. Change how the filename generation on dropbox works and instantiate the NSInputStream with a NSData instead of a file.

To get an NSData from your dictionary you can use an NSKeyedArchiver.