# iOS - Dropbox upload to "App Folder"

Tags: ios, dropbox

In my iOS application, I'm integrating dropbox api to upload files.
While creating app in dropbox.com, i found 2 options. One is full folder availability and one is only "App Folder". I opted for "App folder" and gave a folder name as "xxx".
Then I'm calling the following method that takes full file path as parameter.

```
-(void)uploadFile:(NSString*)filePath
{
    NSString *destDir = @"/";
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:[filePath lastPathComponent] toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath];
}
```

The problem is that the destination directory shouldn't be "/" because I want to upload to "xxx" folder. Even I tried providing destination directory as "xxx" and "/xxx", but it still didn't work out.

Can some one point out what's the wrong thing that I'm doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296648/how-to-upload-nsdictionary-in-memory-to-dropbox-ios

Comment: When you use the "app folder" approach, "/" is mapped to "/Apps/YourAppName".

Comment: @RachelGallen You can see my description using the same method. But how to mention the "destination folder". How can I tell the code to upload the files to "xxx" folder that I create in dropbox app?

Comment: @omz, thanks for clarification. But for testing i created 2 apps. One is full dropbox and one is only one "xxx" folder. Its uploading good to full dropbox folder. But other app which has only "App Folder" is not. Its giving "[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/dropbox/389818471.416380.MOV - (403) Forbidden"

Comment: How do you initialize the `DBSession`? You have to pass the correct value for `root` (either `kDBRootDropbox` or `kDBRootAppFolder`) to `initWithAppKey:appSecret:root:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must be very careful how you are initilazing the DBSession. as mentioned by "omz" in above comments, we have to provide appropriate key if its kDBRootDropbox or kDBRootAppFolder. In my case I'm using 2 different types of accounts which is the main reason for failure. 
I'm very thankful to "omz"

Comment: @ satyam how you fix your problem could you please explain....i am struggling for same.