# Error uploading zip file on dropbox

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

```
-(void) uploadToDropbox {

   NSString *targetFile = PATH_ZIP_FILE;

   DropboxListingView *dropboxView = [[DropboxListingView alloc] initWithPath:@"/" withDelegate:self mode:ImportExportModeExport];
   dropboxView.uploadFiles = [NSArray arrayWithObject:targetFile];

   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dropboxView];

   [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I'm getting this warning

> [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to
>   /1/files_put/dropbox/CurrentDocument.zip - (403) Forbidden

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469154/ios-dropbox-upoad-to-app-folder

Comment: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/403error.htm

Comment: None of the code you shared actually uploads anything. If you want help, you should probably share the code that generates this error. From the 403, I'd say that either your app doesn't have "Full Dropbox" permissions or that something has gone wrong when you linked the user's account.